# Do I need to persist my Notification IDs

Tags: android, notifications

I have an alarm application where users can set multiple alarms. When an alarm goes off the app simply displays a Notification which when clicked will launch the main activity screen and remove the Notification.

Each alarm gets its own Notification which is where my question comes in; if there are multiple Noitifications showing, when the user clicks one I would like to clear all of my app's Notifications. To do this I need to track the IDs of the Notifications currently showing. What is the recommended way of doing this?

I suppose these will need to be persisted as my app's process could be killed as soon as a Notification has been created and displayed. Is my thinking correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To do this I need to track the IDs of the Notifications currently showing.

Or just call `cancelAll()` on `NotificationManager`, to cancel all your outstanding notifications.

> What is the recommended way of doing this?

To be safe, you should use some persistent data store (e.g., file), as your process might go *poof* between alarms.

> I suppose these will need to be persisted as my app's process could be killed as soon as a Notification has been created and displayed. Is my thinking correct?

It could certainly be killed before the next alarm, as discussed in your [other recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11376409/when-does-my-apps-process-die).

Comment: I wasn't aware of cancelAll. That's exactly what I'm looking for!