# When does my app's process die

Tags: android, process

I have an alarm application where users can set multiple alarms. When an alarm goes off (using AlarmManager and a BroadcastReceiver) the app simply displays a Notification.

My app may not be in the foreground for long periods of time so there will be no UI thread running.

My question is, when an alarm goes off and a Notification is displayed, part of my app's code is executed (the BroadcastReceiver and Notification creation). What happens next? Is my app's process immediately killed? Does it remain in some idle state until Android decides to kill it?

(This is all related to another question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11376294/do-i-need-to-persist-my-notification-ids) about persisting Notification IDs. When my app is not running in the foreground and two alarms go off a minute apart, I store the Notification IDs in a static ArrayList. Using the debugger on the second Notification creation it seems that my Notification creator class still holds the first Notification's ID in the ArrayList. This suggests that the process lives between the first and second alarm going off.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What happens next?

Given your avatar, you have a spot o' tea. Or perhaps a pint, depending on time of day and beverage preference.

:-)

> Is my app's process immediately killed?

Probably not.

> Does it remain in some idle state until Android decides to kill it?

Yes. Android terminates processes when it needs RAM to start up other processes. If your process has no running components, it will be relatively high on the list of processes to be terminated. So, your process may not live terribly long, but there is no immediate causal relationship between your `BroadcastReceiver` ending and the process being terminated.

> When my app is not running in the foreground and two alarms go off a minute apart, I store the Notification IDs in a static ArrayList. Using the debugger on the second Notification creation it seems that my Notification creator class still holds the first Notification's ID in the ArrayList. This suggests that the process lives between the first and second alarm going off.

With only a minute between alarms, it is reasonable that your process might stick around, but that is not guaranteed. Of course, running an alarm every minute constantly is unlikely to make you very popular, so make sure the user has some control over this behavior (e.g., can stop your app outright, can modify the polling period).

Comment: Thanks Mark. (The minutely alarms were purely for debug purposes!)

Answer (score 1):

Android has some documentation for that here: [Activity | Process Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ProcessLifecycle)
It all depends on how much memory the system has and the type of process. For BroadcastReceivers it seems as though they are killed first when the device is running low on memory but will persist if it isn't.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I was aware of that page, but didn't know it discussed 'empty processes' which is what is happening in my app.